# Unable to redirect to __init__.py while uploading flask app on ubuntu server

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, web-deployment

I am very new to web development and I am following these two methods (both are same) to deploy flask app to ubuntu vps.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFBRVJPhDGY

my folder structure is like this:

```
|--------cwh
|----------------cwh
|-----------------------static
|-----------------------templates
|-----------------------venv
|-----------------------__init__.py
|----------------cwh.wsgi
```

Below is my code of `__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return "Hello, I love my first website!"
```

Below is my code of `cwh.wsgi` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/cwh/")

from cwh import app as application
application.secret_key = 'Add-secret'
```

Below is the code of `cwh.conf` file that i uploaded at `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 143.198.190.148
        ServerAlias www.saassusar.com
        ServerAdmin saassusar@gmail.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/cwh/cwh.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/cwh/cwh/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/cwh/cwh/static
        <Directory /var/www/cwh/cwh/static/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The **Problem** is that after several attempts I am unable to display `__init__.py` message at my ipaddress. Instead default apache index file is being displayed. Even if there is no static folder, cwh.conf activation doesn't show any error.

Comment: The details provided seem to be insufficient, I tried to reproduce the error but wasn't able to do so. BTW why you are naming the index.py file as ___init___.py Secondly, what is cwh. Better to include complete dependencies and the project structure too needs revision.

Answer (score 0):

The details provided seem to be insufficient, I tried to reproduce the error but wasn't able to do so. BTW why you are naming the index.py file as ___init___.py
Secondly, what is cwh. Better to include complete dependencies and the project structure too needs revision.